# What's wrong with animated GIF images when sending then as MMS through Android Messages service?

Tags: google-messages

**tl;dr** *I am using Android Messages (messages.google.com) to send SMS and MMS messages through my mobile phone directly from my PC (Windows 11). When MMS contains any animated GIF image that image is delivered to the recipient at a minimum dimensions, often barely visible. Can I do anything about this?*

---

When selecting any animated image in at *messages.google.com* the dimensions of an example image are `77x137` pixels:

[image]

During sending the image is quite bigger and has `406x234` pixels:

[image]

But when sending process completes, animation is tiny and has `65x40` pixels only:

[image]

When the example image is received on the phone, it is much bigger (`392x293`), but so blurry that one can easily say that it is artificially enlarged tiny version.

[image]

My gear is Motorola Moto One (first edition; XT1941) with Android 10 on-board. I am using [Play](https://www.play.pl/) (Polish cellular operator; it seems that non-Polish website is not available).

What am I missing? Is this some kind of a bug? Is there anything I can do about this?

Could this be caused by the fact that my cellular operator supports some old version of the MMS protocol and only transfers animated images of a very low size (static, non-animated pictures are sent with much, much bigger resolution, but still far smaller than the original capture from camera).

Comment: Hi @trejder, can you quantify 'quite big' and 'tiny.'  What is the actual size of the image file you are sending.  What is the size of the image file that is ultimately received.  Thank you.  Might be worth attaching each of the files as well (certainly the original).

Comment: Also, please provide your phone make and model as well as your Carrier name.

Comment: @BlindSpots Question edited, I hope that I provided all the answers that you have expected. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Image size I meant size on disk, not resolution, sorry for the confusion.  example 1 MB before, 500KB after etc.  If you download the two pictures from your phone and upload them to the post that would be helpful too (not screen shots).  Ty!  I will help you figure this out.

Comment: @BlindSpots These images comes from the internal repository of Messages Android, after clicking _GIF_ button. They're not stored on my disk. Images stored on disk are sent with usual / normal dimensions through MMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Your Carrier Is Restricting You

---

For some people, MMS size is being limited by a phone setting and increasing the settings in their messaging app can increase the limit. According to Play
this is not the case for you, rather your are network limited. Your carrier Play supports a maximum MMS message size of 300KB.

Maximum MMS varies for mobile carrier to carrier. For example, I believe my carrier limits MMS to 2MB or more.

It is possible that your device messaging app has the maximum set and is "helpfully" automatically compressing the source image.  If you switched to my network, the behavior might even continue for you if you didn't go into your messaging app settings and increase maximum MMS size.

I was pretty surprised by Play's limit.  I asked twice to confirm their answer.  You can test if the information they provided is actually correct by seeing if you can change increase the maximum MMS size in your messaging app by very small increments and then sending test messages with files that are under those maximums.  This would make sure that the information provided was correct.

Additionally you might look at RCS Messaging, which is an imperfect solution but may be a good option for you depending on your needs.

---

### Rich Communication Services (RCS)

---

Play indicated to me that they support RCS messaging. Google refers to their implementation of RCS in their messaging app as 'Chat Features by Google'.

**Pocket Lint:** What is RCS messaging?
https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/news/144258-what-is-rcs-messaging-the-messaging-format-set-to-take-over-your-android-phone

**Play:** How do I get started with RCS Chat?
https://www.play.pl/nowy/uslugi/rcs?id=jak-zaczac-korzystac-z-czatu-rcs

**Chat features by Google FAQ**
https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9487020?hl=en

---

### My Communication with Play

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a very complex and comprehensive answer. I only add (to clarify) that despite Play claims that they support RCS my phone claims that I cannot enable this feature because my network doesn't support chat functionality. Plus, I am using a standard message client from Google and there is nothing about MMS size or MMS at all in Settings and in Settings → Advanced. Thanks again.